# Setting the value of a StructType's StructType

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

Suppose I have a `StructType` ingredient, which is defined as:

```
// volume[0] = quantity
// volume[1] = unit (e.g. mL, L, etc.)
Type *volume[2] = {Type::getFloatTy(this->context), Type::getInt8Ty(this->context)};
ArrayRef<Type*> refs(volume);
this->volumeType = StructType::create(this->context, refs, "volume", true);

Type *types[2] = {this->volumeType, ArrayType::get(Type::getInt8Ty(this->context), 100)};
refs = ArrayRef<Type*>(types);
this->ingredientType = StructType::create(this->context, refs, "ingredient", true);
```

=========================

Suppose I have the following:

```
Ingredient x();
x.volume.unit = 0; // where 0 denotes 'mL'
x.volume.quantity = 100.0;
```

I don't fully understand how to set the `x.volume.unit` value using the LLVM C++ API.

I was reading how the `GetElementPtrInstr` works [from here](http://ranok.github.io/llvm/2014/12/04/llvm-structs.html) and [here](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html).  And essentially, [1](http://ranok.github.io/llvm/2014/12/04/llvm-structs.html) states that I can reference the value(s) I want to assign in a `StructType` by the `ArrayRef` IdxList.  Where `IdxList[0][n]` is the nth element in the struct.  However, what I wasn't sure, and can't get working, is how to set the values in the nested `volume` struct that I have.

I've tried sending a multi-dimensional `ArrayRef` but with no luck.  So I'm sort of stuck with respect to setting a value inside the `volume` StructType which is nested inside the `ingredient` StructType.

Comment: A general suggestion is to write the equivalent code in C and compile with `clang -S -emit-llvm` to see what IR is produced.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting is just an additional argument to getelementptr.

If you access x.volume using getelementptr indices 0, n, then x.volume.unit is acessible using indices 0,n,0 and x.volume.quantity is 0,n,1.

As Ismail Badawi says, you can ask Clang to show you how to do it. If a GEP doesn't do what you want (or any other Instruction, for that matter), you may find it educational to call `x->getType()->dump()` to dump a description of the type you get to stderr.

I suggest that you try setting the unit using 0,0,0, and if it does not work, dump the type of 0,0,0 and see if you recognize it. You give GEP a pointer, the first zero gives you a struct (`x`), the second gives you another struct (it steps into `.volume`), the third probably a float (it steps into `.unit`) and finally GEP implicitly takes the address of that, so the return type of the GEP is a pointer to float. You can give that pointer to a StoreInst to write a float into the struct.